# What is the proper URL Path Definition @font-face web fonts to load

Tags: css, webfonts

I have the following css:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'DezenPro'; src: url('/wp-includes/fonts/dezen_pro_regular.eot'), src: url('/wp-includes/fonts/dezen_pro_regular.woff') format('woff'), src: url('/wp-includes/fonts/dezen_pro_regular.ttf') format('truetype'); }
#slider-wrapper div.cameraContents h1 { font-family: DezenPro, Buenard; font-size: 4.75em; text-align: left; }
```

The font exists on the server at /home/{user}/public_html/wp-includes/fonts/dezen_pro_regular.eot

The css looks fine in the web document.

Yet I cannot get the page to recognize the font face.

Page is located at http://dev.investor-com.com/

The slider is the target for my server-side web font

Comment: Why the gutless drive-by downvote? If there is a reason for the downvote, like I am not asking the question in a manner that meets your standards, why not help me get better at it by explaining your reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the path relative to the CSS-folder. 
I.e. if your CSS-file is in `/home/{user}/public_html/css` you have to write `src: url('../wp-includes/fonts/dezen_pro_regular.eot')`. The `../` stands for 1 folder up. Repeat it if for every folder you have to go up.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help @FelixHagspiel. Your answer caused me to take a closer look at my CSS and when I did I discovered that I had a syntax error in the CSS -- I had extra and stray `src:` for each web font reference between the commas. Once I cleaned it up it worked. <more>

Comment: But it begs the question...if your `url()` solution is correct, then I feel the CSS attributes and syntax are misleading. That is -- to me -- the location reference of where the web font lives is based on server directories rather than web address location off the document root therefore, should the syntax be `path()` rather than `url()` ? Seems illogical to me. But thanks for your help!